# use luabind to call C++ member function inherited form base class

Tags: lua, luabind

## **C++ code here, a console project**

```
class CControl  //: public CGameObject
{
public:
    CControl(){}
    ~CControl(){}

public:
    void AddAnimation(){ cout << "CControl::AddAnimation" << endl;}
};

int  _tmain()
{
    lua_State* L = lua_open();      
    luaL_openlibs(L);               
    open(L);                        

    module(L)
    [
        class_<CControl>("CControl")
            .def(constructor<>())
            .def("AddAnimation",&CControl::AddAnimation)
    ];

    int result = luaL_dofile(L,"scripts/test.lua");
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## ***lua code here using luabind***

```
class 'Button' (Control)
function Button:__init()
    Control:__init()
end

function Button:Create()
    self:AddAnimation()    --call, fail 
end

d = Button()
d:Create()
```

## **Q:**

when i call the inherited function self:AddAnimation() in the Button:Create. Wowwww! "CControl::AddAnimation" has't print out! what's going on? I have check it 2 hours.Frustrating! Any help would really be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get it!! If you want to call Control construtor successfully, you must write code like this
"`Control.(self)`". And By the way, when you want to call memeber function, you should write "`self:AddAnimation`"